# spanish word is not displaying as it is in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, smarty

I have spanish word(Castellón/Castelló) in my database i want to display this word in html as it is in dropdown.but its not showing in spanish language,
its displaying in frontend like CastellÃ³n/CastellÃ³which is wrong

even already i used utf8 encoding in my database.

in local system the text is displaying correctly but while checking in server its showing wrong(CastellÃ³n/CastellÃ³)

i am fetching these data from database in smarty template.

Comment: You're using the wrong character encoding somewhere (In your database, in your PHP script, in the connection between the two, etc).  Everything should be using the same character encoding otherwise issues like this will happen.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? Is the word correctly saved into database?

Comment: you should refer [this](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: yes its storing correctly in database but in prestashop backoffice its showing wrong,so only in front end also its not displaying correctly

Comment: @Ace_Gentile  below is the code  
 <select class="test_code" id="test_code" > 
{foreach $data as $datas}
<option {if $i==1}selected {assign var=cost  value=$datas['shipping_costs']}{/if}class="{$datas['data_name']}"   data-shipping="{$datas['shipping_costs']}" data-tax="{$datas['vat_percentage']}">{$datas['data_name']}</option>
 {/foreach}
  </select>

hear {$datas['data_name']} is not displaying correctly in database